# Reason for Exception java.lang.VerifyError: Bad type on operand stack while writing rule in Mvel

Tags: mvel

I am newbie to Mvel. I am getting a error while executing following mvel expression. This expression executes well for plans which are under size 20 but not greater than that.This behaviour is shown by plans which have size more than 20.

`if (true) { 
    tmp.__tmp = ent.data.plans; 
    if (tmp.__tmp != null) {
       for (int index =0; index < ent.data.plans.size(); index++){
          element=ent.data.plans[index];
          System.out.println(element.name );}}}`

getting error below

> java.lang.VerifyError: Bad type on operand stack
>   Exception Details:
>     Location:
>       ASMAccessorImpl_4263943071452801154960.getValue(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Lorg/mvel2/integration/VariableResolverFactory;)Ljava/lang/Object; @45: invokeinterface
>     Reason:
>       Type 'java/lang/Object' (current frame, stack[1]) is not assignable to integer
>     Current Frame:
>       bci: @45
>       flags: { }
>       locals: { 'ASMAccessorImpl_4263943071452801154960', 'java/lang/Object', 'java/lang/Object', 'org/mvel2/integration/VariableResolverFactory' }
>       stack: { 'java/util/List', 'java/lang/Object' }
>     Bytecode:
>       0x0000000: 2d12 0eb9 0014 0200 b900 1901 00c0 001b
>       0x0000010: 121d b900 2102 00c0 0023 b600 27c0 0029
>       0x0000020: 2d12 2bb9 0014 0200 b900 1901 00b9 002e
>       0x0000030: 0200 b0
>
> at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
>       at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2671)
>       at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3075)
>       at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:412)

Please help.

Comment: didn't know why I am getting exception for for loop. I changed my code to foreach loop now and it is working without giving any error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was getting an exception caused by org.mvel2.optimizers.OptimizationNotSupported .This behavior was shown as DynamicOptimizer doesn't have any fallback when ASM optimizer fails. Reflective optimizers seems to be the good fallback option there and mvel fixed this is the latest version of mvel2 (2.2.7).

I have upgraded mvel2 version and now null-safe bean navigation are working fine.